# Building an hyperplane from a set of points in Python

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, linear-algebra, spatial

I have an hyperplane implementation that looks like this:

```py
class Hyperplane:
    """This is a generalization of the plane in n dimensions
    
    @param unit_normal_vector: the vector that is normal to the plane.
    @param distance_to_origin: the minimal distance in meters of the plane from the origin.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        unit_normal_vector: np.ndarray,
        distance_to_origin: float,
    ):
        self.unit_normal_vector: np.ndarray = unit_normal_vector
        self.distance_to_origin: float = distance_to_origin
    
    @classmethod
    def from_n_points(
        cls,
        points: Union[np.ndarray,List[np.ndarray],List[List[float]]],
    ) -> 'Hyperplane':
        """Build an hyperplane from a set of points
        We need exactly n points to build the hyperplane where n is the dimension of the space.
        """
        X = np.array(points)
        k = np.ones(X.shape[0])
        a=np.dot(np.linalg.inv(X), k)
        
        unit_normal_vector: np.ndarray = a / np.linalg.norm(a)
        distance_to_origin: float = -1 / np.linalg.norm(a)
        
        return cls(
            unit_normal_vector=unit_normal_vector,
            distance_to_origin=distance_to_origin,
        )
```

I hope there is no error... ^_^'

What I need now is to find a way to fit a hyperplane to a set of points where there are more than n points in the points cloud.

It may be a Ransac algorithm or something like this.

Is there a proven method that can be implemented for that?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723294/how-to-determine-the-equation-of-the-hyperplane-that-contains-several-points

Answer (score 1):

You can use a singular value decomposition (SVD) of the point matrix.

```
points = ...   # An n-dim point per row
centroid = np.mean(points, axis=0)
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(points - centroid, full_matrices=False)
```

The normal to the hyperplane is the axis corresponding to the smallest singular value. As long as [np.linalg.svd()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.svd.html) sorts them from largest to smallest, the axis is the last unitary vector of `vh`.

```
normal = vh[-1]
```

The hyperplane is then defined by the `centroid` and the `normal`.