# Find the vector of a plane that consist of four 3d points

Tags: python, numpy

I have four 3D points (blue spheres on the image) arranged in a fixed quadratic manner on a plane.
I want to find the vector that goes up from the center of the plane.
I know that I have to first mean out the 3d points to find the center of the plane but how to figure out that vector?

```
 x    y    z
30, 210, -176
0, 210, -176
30, 180, -176
0, 180, -176
```

[image]

Comment: Four points may not lie in a plane. Try folding a piece of paper.

Comment: In case you are interested in a general method to find the plane that best fits a number of points: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73155466/2148416

Answer (score 1):

Note that you only need *three* points to define a plane. Four points may not define a single plane, but if you can guarantee that your input does, then cool.

Since the vector is perpendicular to the plane, you just need to calculate the cross product of the vector joining one pair of points with the vector joining another pair of points. To ensure that the cross product of these vectors is not zero, we select our pairs such that one of the points is common to both pairs. Since three points are enough to define a plane, this should work fine. In the code below, I use the vector joining point 0 to point 1, and point 0 to point 2:

```
pts = np.array([[30, 210, -176],
                [0, 210, -176],
                [30, 180, -176],
                [0, 180, -176]])

vec1 = pts[0, :] - pts[1, :]
vec2 = pts[0, :] - pts[2, :]

plane_normal = np.cross(vec1, vec2) # array([0, 0, 900])
```

If you want the unit vector, you can normalize `plane_normal` with its L2 norm:

```
plane_normal /= np.linalg.norm(plane_normal) # array([0, 0, 1])
```

We can test this on random points:

```
def plane_norm(pts):
    vec1 = pts[0, :] - pts[1, :]
    vec2 = pts[0, :] - pts[2, :]

    plane_normal = np.cross(vec1, vec2)
    return plane_normal / np.linalg.norm(plane_normal)


np.random.seed(100) # For repeatable results
p = np.random.random((3, 3)) * 5 # three points because they're guaranteed to make a plane

m = p.mean(axis=0) # Mid point
n = plane_norm(p)  # Normal

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

ax.plot_trisurf(p[:, 0], p[:, 1], p[:, 2], alpha=0.5)
ax.plot3D(*m, 'or')
ax.quiver(*m, *n)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

Which results in this plot:
[image]

And after rotating the view to see the plane head-on, it's clear we have the correct vector:
[image]

---

If you wanted to make sure the four points you have make the same plane, you could calculate the normal for the first three and make sure it's close to the normal for the last three:

```
n1 = plane_norm(pts[:3, :])
n2 = plane_norm(pts[1:, :])

if not (np.allclose(n1, n2) or np.allclose(n1, -n2)):
    print("ERROR: the four points are not coplanar")
else:
    print(f"The normal vector is {n1}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As recommended with 3 points, it should work as proven. How could I create a 3d point e.g. in the middle of unit vector? The unit vector should pass through that 3d point.

Comment: Is that point not the `pointOnVector = np.array([m[0] + n[0], m[1] + n[1], m[2] + n[2]])` ?

Comment: @mystic.06 There's no such thing as a "point on a vector". A vector just represents a direction. It passes through any point you like

Comment: But yes, `point_on_vector = m + n` will give you a point moving in the direction of `n` starting from `m`. Note that you can add two numpy arrays like I did above instead of adding the elements individually like you did in `pointOnVector = np.array([m[0] + n[0], m[1] + n[1], m[2] + n[2]])` @mystic.06